# Slicing string in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, string

I have recently learned to slice a string in python programming:

```
>>> word = "Coffee"
>>> word[-3:]
>>> 'fee'
```

I want to do the same thing in vb. I tried to create a conditional state as follows:

```
If Me.FIELD1.Length > 2 Then
    Me.FIELD1 = Me.FIELD1[-3:5]
```

This seems to error out. I'm not sure if vb does slicing the same way python does. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: I don't know Python at all, so I have no idea what that slicing syntax does. But in VB, you can use the `Split` function to split a string.

Comment: Also, you need to be clear about whether you're using VB 6 or VB.NET. They're very different languages with very different available functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Me.FIELD1 = Me.FIELD1.Substring(3);
```

this will return fee
See [VB.Net Substring Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet)

Answer (score 1):

You need to looking into the String.Left, String.Substring, and String.Right functions.